# Adding Leading Zeros in .csv file

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that adds two leading zeros to all the numbers in a particular column.[This script is able to add the two zeros to the column values, but only at the end of the values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtA58.png)

[When I change the order of the variables on line 16 to '$zeros + $employeeNumber', the 7DigitEmployeeNumber column does not include the leading zeros.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJvI4.png)

I have tried converting the data type of $zeros and $employeeNumber but have been unable to get the script to add leading zeros to the column values. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Comment: PLEASE, **_never post images of code/errors/data._** why? lookee ... Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: for a solution to your apparent problem ... use the `-f` string format operator to give you zero-padded numeric _strings_ instead of numbers that naturally don't have leading zeros. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

That's because numbers don't have leading zeros. If you want to pad zeros to the left of the number you have to treat it like a string.

```
$employeeNumber = 73128
$employeeNumberString = $employeeNumber.ToString()
$paddedEmployeeNumberString = $employeeNumberString.PadLeft(7,'0')
```

That will leave `$paddedEmployeeNumberString` with a value of `0073128`.

Comment: You can also use the format operator `$paddedEmployeeNumberString = "{0:0000000}"-f 73128`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the images you posted, this is not just about padding numbers with leading zeroes, but mainly that these leading zeroes 'dissapear' when the csv file is **opened in Excel**.

If you want to have Excel respect those zeroes, write them out in your CSV file prefixed with a TAB character:

```
"`t{0:D7}" -f 73128
```

produces   `0073128`

If you need more total digits, just change `{0:D7}` into `{0:D9}` or `{0:D25}` or..